# find 4 in a row column or diagonal

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an array `N x M` with different chars (`['.','1','0']`) which represent a conncet-4 game board.

I need a FAST, way to check if there are 4 "1"s in a row, column or diagonal.
I currently iterate over the entire array and check 4 directions (`UP,RIGHT,RIGHT-UP,RIGHT-DOWN`), but that is not nearly fast enough.

I just need True or False if '1' is a winner or not.

Suggestion? hopefully with something in numpy.

Comment: you can try something like this `a[(a==1).sum(1)==4]` here a is your matrix

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: It will certainly be easier to do if you use number instead of char, something like `1`, `-1` and `np.nan`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to python, so not sure about how you make use of numpy, but I'd suggest maintaining multiple views of the connect 4 board.

- The rows
- The columns
- The right down diagonals
- The left down diagonals

You'd update all 4 views when you drop a piece in. Connect 4 doesn't allow you to move pieces, so, once a piece is placed it stays put. Working out the diagonal views is fiddly, but if you think of them being able to start off the board it's not too bad. That's the `diag_offset` in the example below.

Then to check for 4 in a row, just join the lists in each view up into a string and find('1111') or find('0000')

Here's an example

```
CONNECT = 4


class Board:

    def __init__(self, max_col=7, max_row=6):
        self.max_col = max_col
        self.max_row = max_row
        self.num_diag = (max_col - (CONNECT-1)) + (max_row - (CONNECT-1)) - 1
        self.diag_offset = max_row - CONNECT
        self.rows = [['.' for _ in range(max_col)] for _ in range(max_row)]
        self.cols = [['.' for _ in range(max_row)] for _ in range(max_col)]
        self.diag1 = [['.' for _ in range(max_row)] for _ in range(self.num_diag)]
        self.diag2 = [['.' for _ in range(max_row)] for _ in range(self.num_diag)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join([''.join(row) for row in self.rows])

    def move(self, x, piece):
        # find empty space in column
        column = self.cols[x]
        y = self.max_row-1
        while not column[y] == '.':
            y -= 1
            if y < 0:
                raise ValueError(f"No space in column {x}")

        self.cols[x][y] = piece
        self.rows[y][x] = piece

        x_diag1 = (self.diag_offset + x) - y
        if 0 <= x_diag1 < self.num_diag:
            self.diag1[x_diag1][y] = piece

        x_diag2 = (x - (CONNECT-1)) + y
        if 0 <= x_diag2 < self.num_diag:
            self.diag2[x_diag2][y] = piece

        return self.check_for_win(piece)

    def check_for_win(self, piece):

        four_pieces = str(piece) * CONNECT

        all_views = self._view(self.cols) + self._view(self.rows) + self._view(self.diag1) + self._view(self.diag2)

        return all_views.find(four_pieces) >= 0

    @staticmethod
    def _view(view):
        # convert supplied 2d list into string. inner list joined without spaces, each inner list joined with a space
        return ' '.join([''.join(each_list) for each_list in view])
```

example game - '0' winning with diagonal going up from bottom left corner

```
board = Board()

print(board)

print(board.move(3, '1'))
print(board.move(3, '0'))
print(board.move(2, '1'))
print(board.move(4, '0'))
print(board.move(2, '1'))
print(board.move(2, '0'))
print(board.move(3, '1'))
print(board.move(3, '0'))
print(board.move(1, '1'))
print(board.move(0, '0'))
print(board.move(4, '1'))
# this is the winning move, so will print True
print(board.move(1, '0'))

print(board)
```

At the end the board has:

```
.......
.......
...0...
..01...
.0101..
01110..
```